# How do I transfer control after a loop in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I would like to translate the C code below into assembly language.

However, I do not see that I need to use the stack in this example.

Moreover, I'd like to know whether or not "beq" saves the address of the following instruction in $ra like "jal" does, for when the loop ends, I would like to get back to the original function foo, and continue the instructions (which here is simply returning.)

```
     int foo(int* a, int N) {
         if(N > 0) 
             {
             for(int i = 0; i != N; i = i + 1) 
                { 
                a[i] = bar(i << 4, a[i]);
                } 
             }
     return N & 7; 
     }
```

```
#assume *a in $a0, N $N in $a1
foo:
slt $t0, $zero, $a1 #put 1 in $t0 if 0 < N
li $t1,0 # use $t1 as loop counter
beq $t0, 1, loop  # enter loop if 0 < N
and $v0, $a1, 7 # do bitwise and on N and 7 and save in $v0 as return value

loop:
beq $t1, $a1, exit # exit loop when i = N
sll $t3, $t1, 2 # obtain 4 * i
add $t3, $a1, $t3 # obtain address of a[i] which is address of a plus 4i
lw $t3, o($t3)  # load a[i] into $t3
sll $t4, $t1, 4 #perform  i<< 4 and save in $t4
# the 2 previous load arguments for bar
jal bar # assume bar saves return value in $v2
sw $t3, 0($v1)
j loop

exit:
and $v0, $a1, 7
```

Comment: you jump conditionally ... based on some condition :) -- looks like mips calls those branch instructions, it is different based on arch... but yeah agree with Jesper below... at least look at the output from a compiler...

Comment: "I would like to translate the C code below into assembly language." - Why? Why not let the compiler take care of that? It's *usually* much better at it than humans.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's clearly an exercise to learn assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beq` is for conditional branching, not calling — it changes the `PC` (conditionally) but not `$ra`.  We use it to translate structured statements (e.g. if, for) into the if-goto style of assembly language.

> However, I do not see that I need to use the stack in this example.

You ***must*** to use the stack for this code because the call to `bar` (as in `jal bar`) will wipe out *`foo`s* `$ra`, and while `bar` will be able to return back to `foo`, `foo` will not be able to return to its caller.  Since this requires a stack, you will need [prologue and epilogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue) to allocate and release some stack space.

Your code is not properly passing parameters to `bar`, `i << 4`, for example, should be passed in `$a0`, while `a[i`] should be passed in `$a1`.

You do not have a return instruction in `foo` — it is missing a `jr $ra`.

Comment: nitpick: if you know which registers `bar()` clobbers, `foo` can keep a copy of its `$ra` in a register that will survive, instead of save/restore on the stack.  (That means foo and bar need to have different custom calling conventions, otherwise `foo` would need to save/restore its caller's value in that register.)

Answer (score 0):

**If either of your `beq` instructions did set `$ra`, those wouldn't be useful points to return back to.**  But since you asked:

> I'd like to know whether or not "beq" saves the address of the following instruction in $ra like "jal" does

If the instruction mnemonic doesn't end with `al` (which stands for And Link), it doesn't save a return address in `$ra`.

Classic MIPS has the following instructions that link, from this [somewhat incomplete reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) (missing `nor` and IDK what else).

- `jal target` (Jump And Link)
- `BGEZAL $reg, target` (conditional Branch if >= 0 And Link)
- `BLTZAL $reg, target` (conditional Branch if < 0 And Link)

Note that the conditional branches are effectively branching on the sign bit of the register.

`bal` is an alias for `bgezal $zero, target`, useful for doing a PC-relative function call.  (MIPS branches use a fully relative encoding for branch displacement, MIPS jumps use a region-absolute encoding that replaces the low 28 bits of PC+4.  This matters for position-independent code).

---

None of this is particularly relevant to your case; your `foo` needs to save/restore `$ra` on entry/before `jr $ra` because you need to call `bar` with a `jal` or `bal`.  Using a linking branch as the loop branch wouldn't affect anything (except to make your code even less efficient, and make performance worse on real CPUs that do return-address prediction with a special predictor that assumes `jal` and `jr $ra` are paired properly).

Using `bal` / `jal` doesn't automatically make the thing you jump to ever return; that only happens if the target ever uses `jr $ra` (potentially after copying `$ra` somewhere else then restoring it).